the Toast message in the given function is not showning in the UI
In this handleFileEvent function when selecting multiple files it should display the message "Multiple Files Not Allowed" but not sure why the message is not displaying.
const handleFileEvent = (e: any) => {
    const chooseFiles = Array.from(e.target.files);
    if (chooseFiles.length > 1) {
      ShowToastMessage('Warning', "Can't choose multiple files");
    } else {
      handleUploadFiles(chooseFiles);
      e.target.value = '';
      console.log(chooseFiles);
    }
  }

  const handleUploadFiles = (files: any) => {
    const uploaded = [...uploadfile]
    files.some((file: any) => {
      const fileName = file.name.toLowerCase()
      const fileExtension = fileName.slice(((fileName.lastIndexOf('.') - 1) >>> 0) + 2)
      if (allowedExtensions.includes(fileExtension)) {
        if (uploaded.findIndex((f: any) => f.name === file.name) === -1) {
          uploaded.push(file)
        }
      } else {
        ShowToastMessage(
          'Warning',
          `${file.name} is not allowed. Allowed extensions: 3gp,aac,act,aiff,amr,ape,au,avi,awb,bdvm,bmp,dat,dct,dds,dib,doc,docx,dss,dvf,dvr-ms,eml,flac,flv,gif,gsm,html,ifo,iklax,ivs,jfif,jpe,jpeg,jpg,m2ts,m4a,m4p,m4v,mht,mkv,mmf,mov,mp3,mp4,mpc,mpeg,mpg,msg,msv,mts,oga,ogg,ogm,ogv,opus,pdf,pjpeg,png,pps,ppt,pptx,qt,ra,raw,rm,rtf,sbe,sln,tga,tif,tiff,ts,tta,txt,vox,wav,webm,wma,wmv,wtv,wv,xls,xlsx,x-png,csv`,
          ToastMessageType.Warning,
        )
      }
    })
    const e = { ...gridHelper.entities }
    e['uploadfiles'] = uploaded
    gridHelper.setEntities(e)
    setUploadfiles(uploaded)
  }


Can you share ShowToastMessage function ?

the ToastMessage Function is a global  Component called in this page
